# MPChart in Android Built Pie chart by custom values

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

This is the method of library setData. I have four values `q1,q2,q3,q4` total of all 4 so my total is supposed 10000 `q1=1000,q2=500,q3=500,q4=8000`. so how do i passed all these values in this and generate my own graph see this data is coming from my API so for every user data if different and chart built according to that data values.

```
   private void setData(int count, float range){

    float mult = range;

    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    // IMPORTANT: In a PieChart, no values (Entry) should have the same
    // xIndex (even if from different DataSets), since no values can be
    // drawn above each other.
    for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++) {
      //yVals1.add(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 5, i));
        yVals1.add(new Entry((float)(dislikeval), i));
    }

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++)
        xVals.add(mParties[i % mParties.length]);

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "Election Results");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);

    // add a lot of colors
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    //dataSet.setSelectionShift(0f);

    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    data.setValueTextSize(11f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    data.setValueTypeface(tf);
    mChart.setData(data);

    // undo all highlights
    mChart.highlightValues(null);

    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code :

```
private void setData() {
        // Label for each slice
        String[] valueArray = new String[] { "Q1", "Q2", "Q3" };
        // Values for pie chart
        ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        yVals1.add(new Entry(1000, 0));
        yVals1.add(new Entry(2000, 2));
        yVals1.add(new Entry(3000, 1));

        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.length + 1; i++)
            xVals.add(valueArray[i % valueArray.length]);

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "");
        dataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
        dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);

        // add a lot of colors

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

        dataSet.setColors(colors);
        //dataSet.setSelectionShift(0f);

        PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
        data.setValueTextSize(12f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setValueTypeface(tf);
        mChart.setData(data);

        // undo all highlights
        mChart.highlightValues(null);

        mChart.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: it is not generating the piechart

Comment: u r also fetching data from server

Comment: no, I am using sqlite database, I have just changed this function and pass array as arguments for both values and labels